# WebForm read xml file issue

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have an WebForm in my website and i try to read xml file from my local computer:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\ServerXml\Message.xml");
XmlNodeList NodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("message");
```

And when i run this method i get Exception:

```
Could not find file 'C:\ServerXml\Message.xml'
```

The file exist in this path for sure.

Why it won't find the file? it is because something i need to define in the iis? i run this on the local with run in VS2010

Comment: double check the `filename` to make sure you have the case correctly is `Message.xml` actually `message.xml`?

Comment: How do you expect a **server-side** code running on a potentially remote web server to be able to load and process a file from your local harddisk? This won't ever work - you'll have to first **upload** the file to the web server, save it, and **then** process it from the location where it was saved on the server side...

Comment: are you running this locally if so it should work I just tested the `XDocument doc =` code on my local and I can load an `xml` file running a console app. you need to look at how to use `Server.MapPath` if you are doing this or running it on a remote web server

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user you are running under has the right autorisation for the given folder.